# How to get number of used columns in a row in QXlsx

Tags: c++, qt

I have an excel file that I'm trying to parse in Qt Framework using QXlsx library. I'm Stuck on calculating the number of last Used column in a row, because each row has a different number of used columns. see the picture below as an example.

[image]

I have already tried the following code

```
QXlsx::Document doc("data.xlsx");
int lastColumn = doc.dimention().columnCount();
```

But this line will return the number of last used column in the excel file
in my example it will be column 'F' which will be 6 for all rows which is incorrect.

Any hint will be appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching and asking for help the way to get the last column in QXlsx library as suggested in this [replay](https://forum.qt.io/post/673102) is to check for non-empty cell in reverse in each row and break the loop if i found the last non-empty cell. As following

```
QXlsx::Document doc("data.xlsx");
QVariant cell;
int number;
int lastColumn = doc.dimention().columnCount();

for(int column = lastColumn; 0!=column; column--){
     cell = doc.read(row,column);
     if(cell.toString()!=""){
        number = column;
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Mistake in method doc.dimention(), use dimension() instead, see documentation at https://github.com/QtExcel/QXlsx/blob/499901003f02da34f7fbc1ec214a24e4dc128b74/QXlsx/header/xlsxdocument.h#L91